# Blueprintjs Table hide overflow-s scrollbar

Tags: blueprintjs

Is it possible to hide table scrollbar ?

In my particulary case i need to set `overflow-y: hidden`

I found html tag that set's overflow option, and maybe can override it's overflow, but it will take multiple `div > div > div` in css selector witch i think is not the right way.

**Update**

For now i done this using css:

```
div.table-no-overflow > div > div > div.bp-table-body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: custom CSS is the preferred way to change things like this. However, you should be able to write a simpler selector rather than tracing the exact DOM structure. It should be as simple as:

```
.bp-table-body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: i use multiple blueprint tables in my project, and some need this scrollbar, so i can't add this to global css. I thought maybe it is hidden prop or method i can set, thanks for attention.

Comment: you can easily target the selector to one or more tables by adding more classnames.